# Is TCP or TCP/IP synchronous or a-synchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization, synchronous, tcp

From a Google search I saw it being mentioned that the HTTP protocol is considered synchronous due to the request and response happening while the connection remains open (http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_http_is_asynchronous?#slide=11). I know the link is not authoritative, but since HTTP and TCP/IP are both protocols, I was wondering whether the same question could be asked of TCP/IP: "Is TCP or TCP/IP synchronous or a-synchronous ?".

The closest insight I found was "[What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous transmission in TCP/ IP socket programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481397/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-transmission-in-tcp)", but this was in relation to socket programming.

I'm not sure if TCP or TCP/IP as a protocol on its own can be generally regarded as synchronous or a-synchronous, or whether I'm asking the right question. I hope somebody can provide further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> The HTTP protocol is considered synchronous due to the request and response happening while the connection remains open.

No it isn't. This statement is basically nonsense. HTTP is a request-response protocol all right, but there is also request piplelining, which complicates the picture considerably. If you have a source for this claim please cite it.

> So is TCP or TCP/IP synchronous or a-synchronous?

With respect to the API, TCP/IP input/output from/to the network is asynchronous with respect to the API, but there is also an asyncrhonous version of the API that lets the API itself continue while the application does something else.

Your question doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: From http://wiki.answers.com: "HTTP is synchronous: a client issues a request and waits for the corresponding response before anything else is done. (...) So the real answer to the question as it stands is: HTTP is not asychronous" (http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_http_is_asynchronous?#slide=3 and http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_http_is_asynchronous?#slide=4)

Comment: All I can make of that is that wiki.answers.com is contradicting itself. It's not an authoritiative source. 'Synchronous' doesn't really have the meaning they use, and neither does 'asynchronous', even though it's unfortunately used that way in the name of AJAX.